# Process text file with timestamps and output the last row per second

Tags: awk

I have a csv file which contains a nanosecond-resolution timestamp in the format `"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.fffffffffZ"` followed by some data

```
2021-04-26T09:30:04.786235633Z,102 
2021-04-26T09:30:04.786235633Z,524 
2021-04-26T09:30:04.786235633Z,566 
2021-04-26T09:30:04.791050014Z,391 
2021-04-26T09:30:09.882687589Z,922 
2021-04-26T09:30:09.886405549Z,744 
2021-04-26T09:30:09.886405549Z,702 
2021-04-26T09:30:14.986237837Z,436 
2021-04-26T09:30:14.986237837Z,636 
2021-04-26T09:30:14.986298532Z,353 
2021-04-26T09:30:14.986298532Z,445 
2021-04-26T09:30:14.986298532Z,785 
2021-04-26T09:30:14.986298532Z,917 
2021-04-26T09:30:20.086229659Z,195 
2021-04-26T09:30:20.086229659Z,228 
2021-04-26T09:30:20.086229659Z,486 
2021-04-26T09:30:20.086229659Z,41 
2021-04-26T09:30:20.086229659Z,421 
2021-04-26T09:30:20.090214746Z,386 
2021-04-26T09:30:25.186477272Z,678 
2021-04-26T09:30:25.186477272Z,198 
2021-04-26T09:30:25.190264104Z,459 
2021-04-26T09:30:25.190460283Z,123 
2021-04-26T09:30:25.190460283Z,318 
2021-04-26T09:30:26.442994013Z,200
```

I would like to process it in such a way that only the **last row per second** is output:

```
2021-04-26T09:30:04.791050014Z,391 
2021-04-26T09:30:09.886405549Z,702 
2021-04-26T09:30:14.986298532Z,917 
2021-04-26T09:30:20.090214746Z,386 
2021-04-26T09:30:25.190460283Z,318 
2021-04-26T09:30:26.442994013Z,200
```

Is it possible to do this with awk or some such tool?

Comment: Are the lines always already in chronological order?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes they are

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is possible: keep track of the last second and corresponding line, and whenever the second changes, output the memorised line:

```
awk -F. 'NR > 1 && lastsec != $1 { print lastline }
         { lastsec = $1; lastline = $0 }
         END { if (NR) print }'
```

Comment: Split on `.`, genius! Thank you!

Comment: @Stéphane I don’t understand why `NR > 1` is better than `lastsec`, could you explain?

Comment: Not much better (though would work better if `lastsec` was set but to an empty string or some representations of zero), I only changed it for consistency with the `if (NR)` I added in `END`, which you could also change to `if (lastsec)` (with the same caveat) if you like.

Comment: Ah right, I’d missed the `if (NR)` in the `END` block. I’m relying on the default value of a variable, given that it’s not set beforehand. The advantage of testing against `lastsec` is that it also skips empty lines in the middle of the input. For robustness there should be a check against `NF` in the second block too...

Comment: Technically, it would skip lines for which the first field is either empty or some numeric representation of zero, not just empty lines.

Comment: Yes, it would...

Answer (score 7):

With GNU `sort`, you could do:

```
<file.csv sort -r | sort -suk1,1.19
```

That is `sort` by reverse chronological order, and then sort the result in forward chronological order but only considering the first 19 characters to ignore subseconds and with `-u` (for unique) select the first (which will be the more recent one because of the previous `sort` and the `-s` stable order) of those that have the same 19 character key.

Instead of `-k1,1.19`, you could also use `-t. -k1,1` to select the part of the line before the first `.` as the sort key.

If the input file is already in chronological order, you can replace the first `sort` with `tac` (or `tail -r` on some systems).

Answer (score 2):

Using **Python** in conjunction with the `groupby` method in the `itertools` module.

The grouping is done on the time (zeroth field) and from this group, the last element is the target line for the group.

```
python3 -c 'import itertools as it, sys
fs,rs = ofs,ors = ".","\n"
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  print(*[list(group)[-1].rstrip(rs) for key,group in it.groupby(f,lambda x: x.split(fs)[0]) if key],sep=ors)
' file
```

---

The stream editor ,sed, can handle this way:

```
sed -Ee '
  $!N
  /^([^.]+\.).*\n\1/!P
  D
' file
```

Essentially, we compare two consecutive lines and in particular their first dot delimited fields. Only if they do not match do we print .

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 'N;/^\([^.]*\.\).*\n\1/D;P;D' file
```

The main feature in command D. It not only removes the first string from the pair, but also restarts the action at the beginning of the script with the remaining string in buffer.